# Regex with jqBootstrapValidation not working

Tags: jquery, regex, jqbootstrapvalidation

I have got a problem with RegEx in jqBootstrapValidation.
Sadly I have got no idea of RegEx so I copy and paste all my RegExs. That works fine most of the time. **Thanks to anyone here who post all these!**

This does not work:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Street + Number</label><br>
    <div class="controls">
      <input class="form-control" type='text' name='schoolStreet' data-validation-regex-regex="^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])" data-validation-regex-message="Not valid" />
      <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result: Always wrong

**The same div does work with an easier RegEx like "[a-z]"**

I also tried to escape it like this :

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])/
```

Doesn't work.

```
@^(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*$@i
```

Doesn't work either

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you actually want to match with your regex? Give us some samples that shall match and that shouldn't match.

Comment: The RegEx are working fine. I tested them here -> https://regex101.com/ The Problem is that they do not work with jqBootstrapvalidation...